Fetch cloudflare worker in the same zone unsupported
I'm using javascript cloudflare worker and I'm making a fetch request to another server, same cloudflare account, written on golang.
Server responds with 404 Not Found, error code: 1042, which means

Worker tried to fetch from another Worker on the same zone, which is unsupported."


according to https://developers.cloudflare.com/workers/observability/errors/

Is where any configuration option or workaround make requests from one server to another in the same cloudflare account?

Are both of your Cloudflare Workers deployed under the same subdomain or different subdomains?
Example: Are they both under 'example.com' or are they under different subdomains like 'worker1.example.com' and 'worker2.example.com'

A possible workaround will be to route the request through an external service, such as an API gateway or another server outside of Cloudflare's restrictions.
